# Which method is faster ob.setText(""+int) or ob.setText(String.valueOf(int);

Tags: java, android, string, optimization

Want to know which method is faster in android. Just for knowledge.

```
TextView t;
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_ID);

int number=5;
```

```
t.setText(""+number);
```

or

```
t.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

Comment: Try it out! You can write a for loop that runs a million times and run a timer to see how long it takes to do each operation a million times. A million sounds like a lot, but it should take less than 5 seconds.

Comment: there's evidence now as to why t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is faster.

Comment: Check out why it is faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709549/14921272

Answer (score 3):

`String.valueOf(int)` is fastest, as most direct. However this is a micro-optimisation. The compiler probably does optimize this itself.

`"" + number` would do a conversion too, and a string concatenation. Theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

***`t.setText(String.valueOf(number))` is measurably faster***. Here is proof from running a simple benchmark where each of the methods, `t.setText(""+number)` and `t.setText(String.valueOf(number))` were run 100 million times using `Math.random() * 10000` as `number`. This process was repeated 3 times over so 2 methods, run 100 million times each, times 3, is 600 million repetitions - hopefully convincing as to its trustworthiness.

```
100000000 iterations:
4265705942 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
4405272846 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 1.0327184 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is -139.56711 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
100000000 iterations:
4222272915 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
4082684488 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 0.9669399 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is 139.58861 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
100000000 iterations:
4139763946 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
4084830689 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 0.98673034 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is 54.933247 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
```

As you can see, `t.setText(String.valueOf(number))` ran faster by `54.933247 milliseconds` once and `139.58861 milliseconds` another. Meanwhile, `t.setText(""+number)` ran `139.56711 milliseconds` faster in one trial. As you can see, they are comparable - the major influencing factor that caused their oscillation was the use of a pseudorandom number. As you can see below, `t.setText(String.valueOf(number))` is faster in all three trials when the number is set to 1.

```
100000000 iterations:
1292082781 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
922339178 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 0.71383905 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is 369.74362 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
100000000 iterations:
835123611 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
801558559 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 0.9598083 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is 33.565056 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
100000000 iterations:
824446908 nanoseconds
^^empty string + number^^
776221856 nanoseconds
^^String.valueOf()^^
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) takes 0.94150615 the time of t.setText(""+number).
t.setText(String.valueOf(number)) is 48.225086 milliseconds faster than t.setText(""+number)
```

In sum, ***`t.setText(String.valueOf(number))`*** is slightly faster than `t.setText(""+number)`.

Thanks to [SeanF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709549/14921272), here is an explanation of why it's faster:

String addition results in the compiler creating a StringBuilder instance, followed by append calls for each added element, followed by a call to `StringBuilder.toString()` to create the resulting concatenated String instance.
So, ""+number creates a StringBuilder, appends a number using the same conversion as `String.valueOf`, and then creates a String instance from the StringBuilder with `StringBuilder.toString`.
`String.valueOf(number)` avoids the StringBuilder, just using the value from `String.valueOf.`

Comment: Though the question just was which is faster, I would like to know the reason. Could you give an explanation?

Comment: @ChristianB no! I could not! That's a fascinating question and I would like to know! Do you know?

Comment: Maybe we should ask

Comment: I can only guess `""+number` is slower because of string concatenation

Comment: If anyone wants to answer WHY is it faster. :)

Comment: @ChristianB Check out why it is faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65709549/14921272